# How to create alert or notification badge

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces 6.0. I want to have the notification number on the tab.
[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ye9qW.png)

This is no longer available...
[Primefaces notification bar](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/notificationBar.jsf)

How can I make it?

Comment: You can write your own css..

Comment: Your link to notification bar should be https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/notificationBar.xhtml

Comment: Hi Sharan, i know css is one of the way..

Comment: Hi Unknown 1, that one is not what i am looking for